# How to access an element by index position of a String [] array from Visualforce pages without error?

Tags: apex, visualforce

When I try to access an element by a particular position from within a VF page, it provides this error below:

> Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.1' Unknown property
>   'VisualforceArrayList.2' Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.3

'

I know these '`{!criteria[1]}`', '`{!criteria[2]}`', and '`{!criteria[3]}`' are populating correctly on my VF page when i first access the page from a record, but when i click on any commandbutton, errors regarding VisualforceArrayList in the above would supply.

Below are my portions of my VF Page and Controller/method that are relevant:

**VF Page**

```
<apex:pageBlock id="CriteriaSelection">
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3" title="Select Your Criteria" rendered="{!displayFields}">
    <apex:repeat value="{!criteriaFields}" var="criteria">
      <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!criteria[1]}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!fieldPicklist}" />
      </apex:selectList>
      <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!criteria[2]}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!numberOperators}" />
      </apex:selectList>
      <apex:inputText value="{!criteria[3]}" />
    </apex:repeat>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Class/Method:

```
public GoalsExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    goal = [SELECT Id, Name, StartDate__c, EndDate__c, Object__c, Field__c FROM Goal__c WHERE Id=:controller.getRecord().Id];

    mapAllObjects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

    sortedObjectNames = new List<String>();

    sortedObjectNames.addAll(mapAllObjects.keyset());
    sortedObjectNames.sort();

    objectPicklistOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    objectPicklistOptions.add(new SelectOption('None', '--None--'));

    for(String s : sortedObjectNames) {
        objectPicklistOptions.add(new SelectOption(s, mapAllObjects.get(s).getDescribe().getLabel() + ' [' + s + ']'));
    }

    newNameOfFields = new List<String>();
    displayFields = false;

    SetOperatorLists();

    criteriaList = [SELECT Id, Field__c, Operator__c, Value__c FROM GoalCriterion__c WHERE Goal__c=:goal.Id];

    criteriaFields = new List<String[]>();
    for(GoalCriterion__c criterion : criteriaList) {
        String[] values = new String[] {criterion.Id, criterion.Field__c, criterion.Operator__c, criterion.Value__c};
        criteriaFields.add(values);
    }
    /*criteriaOne = criteriaFields[1];
    criteriaTwo = criteriaFields[2];
    criteriaThree = criteriaFields[3];*/

    if(goal.Object__c != null && goal.Object__c != 'None') {

        selectedObject = goal.Object__c;

        selectedField = goal.Field__c;
        ShowFields();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is on this line and related other places where you are using `criteria` local variable.

```
<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!criteria[1]}">
```

The `value` attribute of `apex:selectList` is associated to a controller class variable. So whenever the VF page is encountering `{!criteria[i]}`, it considers that to be a class variable, and attempts to set the value on that variable in the class and fails because there's none available.

In order to fix this, you will need to make sure to bind the `value` attribute to a class variable in the controller. Refer to the excerpt from the [documentation of apex:selectList](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm) for the `value` attribute.

> A merge field *that references the controller class variable* that is associated with this selectList. For example, if the name of the associated variable in the controller class is *myListSelections*, use *value="{!myListSelections}"* to reference the variable.

So instead of what you have right now, you will need to define all those class variables in your controller class and utilize them on `apex:selectList`. May be something as below:

```
// in controler
public String criteria1 { get; set; }

// on VF page
<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!criteria1}">
```

Comment: Thanks Jayant - I ended up feeding an existing list into an apex:repeat tag to rectify the error instead of having to use list<String []> type and worked!!